# How to get Multiple iframes content at once using selenium in java

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, iframe, phantomjs

Here I want to get the pagesource of a webpage.Webpage has iframe.I am able to get the page content but not the iframe content using below code

```
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
driver.get(url);
Thread.sleep(10000);
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

But,I can get the iframe content but not the page content using below code

```
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
driver.get(url);
Thread.sleep(10000);
WebElement iframe=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='selection']/div/iframe"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

Here,I want to get pagecontent and iframe content at same time.

One more scenario is if a web page has multiple iframes I need to get all iframe content along with page content.

Is it possible to get content of both iframe and main page content..?

Answer (score 0):

Write a method to get the content, something like:

```
public void getIframeContent()
   try
   {
      WebElement iframe=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='selection']/div/iframe"));
      driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
      System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
   }
   finally
   {
      driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
   }
```

Comment: This prints the iframe source which the OP already figured out. The OP is asking for a combined solution of printing all iframe contents inside of the parent markup.

Comment: Yah it will print the iframe source but not the page source.If I use driver.getPagesource() in finally block instead of try it gives page source not iframe source.I want both.

Comment: Webdriver isn't going to do this for you. You would need to write a method that first gets the full page source, then gets the iframe source and injects it at the right place. Is there an actual reason you need to do this as I can't think of a practical application?

Comment: I am crawling a webpage where I need to get the elements which are there in iframe as well as main page. So,I need to get the entire content to continue with further operations.

Comment: So you dont actually need to have all the content at the same time. Your method should be gettting the elements in the main page and then the iframes seperately .

Comment: Once I get the webpage content I need to display the same web page in our tool and then i will look for elements in a page.So,to display a page i need complete content.

Comment: If it is not possible to achieve my target with driver object  I want same with javascript so that I can continue with JavascriptExecuter Interface.